# Reading the Same Image Stream Twice

Tags: c#, wpf, image, stream

I want to get dimensions of the image and stream the image to an object in the same time or after.
Code Like this.

```
string page = pages[pageComboBox.SelectedIndex].pageImage;          // image url
var stream = web.OpenRead(page);
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.StreamSource = stream;                // First read stream 
stream.Position = 0;                         // tried
bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bitmap.EndInit();
pageIMG.Source = bitmap;
Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);      // Second read stream
MessageBox.Show("Image Height = " + image.Height + " Image Width = " + image.Width);
```

I did use the position thing but it gives me an error -

> 'This stream does not support seek operations.'

Please help...

Comment: Well, what is `stream` and where did it come from? Indeed, not all streams can be seeked

Comment: Its just a image from url.I'm doin a webscrapper so.

Comment: It seems to be a `Network` ish stream. You may not read it twice. But you can copy it to a `Memory` or a `FileStream` and then read it multiple times.

Comment: So i cannot read it twice like it without copyin it to memory ?

Comment: you can directly save  the image like this. MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(your byte array);
Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
image.Save("image.bmp");

Comment: i dont want to save the image i just want to forward stream to image and get its dimention bu when put it in the code it doesnt give me any dimention.(Always gives me heigh 1 width 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the source stream to a MemoryStream:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.StreamSource = memoryStream;
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.EndInit();
    ...

    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
    ...
}
```

However, it seems pointless to read the stream a second time into a WinForms Image. You could instead just query the BitmapImage's PixelWidth and PixelHeight properties:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.StreamSource = memoryStream;
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.EndInit();
    ...

    MessageBox.Show(
        "Image Height = " + bitmap.PixelHeight +
        " Image Width = " + bitmap.PixelWidth);
}
```

Comment: I did the pixelheight but neither of them returns true value.It still returns 1 for heigh 1 for width :S

Comment: Copying to a MemoryStream may still be necessary, e.g. to make sure a web response stream is read to the end. Can't remember the exact situation, but I had to do that once.

Comment: MemoryStream worked but i had to add `memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);stream.Close();` after the CopyTo. Thank you so much.